# Create custom mappings of Mathematica Expressions => Java Objects?

Tags: java

I would like to call a JLink-based java function from Mathematica with a Mathematica Span[] object as shorthand, like so...

```
<< JLink`
MyJavaPackage`myStaticMethod[ variable1, variable2, 1 ;; 10 ]
```

I would like to convert the `Span[1, 10]` object into a Java object automatically (actually, a `scala.range` object)

I know you can specify the mapping of complex values in Mathematica using 
`SetComplexClass["classname"]`. Is there any general equivalent, so I can do the above conversion automatically? I am thinking I need something like the inverse of `MakeJavaExpr[]`...

The alternative would be, I guess, to specify in Mathematica, in the MyJavaPackage` scope, something like...

```
 MyJavaPackage`myStaticMethod[ variable1, variable2, span_Span ]:=
      myStaticMethod[ variable1, variable2, JavaNew["scala.Range", span[[1]], span[[2]]]
```

... that would preclude doing this for non-static Java functions though, I guess.

Thank you for your help!